# Smooth shading getting flat when normals applied

Tags: normals, normal-map, smooth

im relatively new to 3D modeling, i watched quite some tutorials and started modeling some stuff, but im having a problem and cant find anything to help me solve it. To the problem then. So im modeling a table and got the textures done on Substance painter, then in blender everything is fine until i put in the normal map, i mean i dont even have to put anything, as soon as i connect the image texture (and yes, its on non color data) to the normal map node the smooth shading on the bevels of the table dissapears and it gets flat and ugly. Im using version 2.79 because im creating custom content for the Sims 4 and gotta use that version.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Add screenshots